# Almost $\sigma $-additivity

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $(B_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ $\subset S$:

1. If $\mu (A_n \cap A_m)=0$ for all $n\neq m \Rightarrow \mu (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu (A_n)$
2. If $\mu (A_n\ \triangle\ B_n)=0\ \ \forall n\in \mathbb N$ then:
   $$i)\ \mu(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n\ \triangle \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}B_n)=0$$
   $$ii)\ \mu(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n\ \triangle \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}B_n)=0$$
   $$iii)\ \mu(\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} A_n\ \triangle \varlimsup_{n \to \infty} B_n)=0$$
   $$iv)\ \mu(\varliminf_{n \to \infty} A_n\ \triangle \varliminf_{n \to \infty} B_n)=0$$

I don't know yet how to approach for the second one, but for the first one I think I need to prove first the inclusion-exclusion principle, any idea?

Any suggestions or ideas for the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by $A\oplus B$?

Comment: @David I think the OP means the symmetric difference $A\triangle B$.

Comment: Yes, as @David stated, with $\oplus $ I mean the symmetric difference.

Comment: Hint: $\mu\left(\bigcup A_n\triangle B_n\right)=0$, and everywhere except on the union $x\in A_n$ if and only if $x\in B_n$.